# retention policy for sharepoint 2010 Transfer to another location is Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, retention

I have created retention policy in SP2010 for Library and Document as folder based with some rules, also set information management policy and Expiration policy Timer job as in one after another running sequence, these all working fine for "Move in Recycle bin" option, but its not working  for "Transfer To another Location" option, where I have already created the location as Drop off library using the Web service URL from Submission point.

If I am Sending the Document manual as "Send To " option its moving the document to Drop off library properly, but By Running the Above mentioned timer job , Documents are not moving to document even the Defined retention stage is already accorded.

and the "Compliance details" displaying status as Completed without moving the document and no error logging for same case.

Please guide me where If I am missing some thing in process...

Answer (score 1):

Is this Drop off library located in the same site? If so this will not work because according to Microsoft,  **It was as per design**. If you try to move documents to a different location using Retention policy, you have to move it a library in a **different** site collection. Preferably ‘Records center‘ site collection. Main idea of Microsoft is to have one Archival or Records center site collection for the whole organization.

So, if you are trying to move documents after expiration to a library in same site or site collection, you can use a workaround to start a workflow on expiration date which moves the document to archival library.

Hope this helps. [Source](http://sharepointviews.com/sharepoint-retention-policy-not-working-solved/)